# Extracting multiple data files from a single csv file

Tags: r, csv, na

I am reading in a large number of .csv files. Each of these has four sets of data separated by three blank columns. Once the entire file has been read in, and assigned to a data frame, the content of the blank columns is interpreted as NA. There is over one hundred of these files, and I cannot guarantee a constant number of columns for each set of data.

Starting with the initial data frame, I need to create four separate data frames. I cannot figure out how I would make use of the labels in this case. A label describing each of the four data sets marks its first column, but all of the other column names get automatic names (V2, V3, V4, etc.) After finding a list of label locations, I can compute the second data set as columns 6:25, but R doesn't want to identify columns by numbers: only names.

The other tool I can think of using is to find the NA columns and pull out the data between them. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to do this. The insistence on column names is still a problem.

I would appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you.

Comment: I just found a solution. I transposed the data frame, picked out a portion of it by numbered rows, and then transposed again. Seems silly, but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work with column indices.

I tested with this fake file:

```
test = structure(list(testA1 = 1:5, testA2 = 1:5, testA3 = 1:5, c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    testB1 = 1:5, testB2 = 1:5, c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), testC1 = 1:5, testC2 = 1:5, testC3 = 1:5, 
    testC4 = 1:5, c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), testD1 = 1:5, testD2 = 1:5), .Names = c("testA1", 
"testA2", "testA3", "", "", "", "testB1", "testB2", "", "", "testC1", 
"testC2", "testC3", "testC4", "", "testD1", "testD2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

write.csv(test, "test.csv", na="", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Then, you can try this function:

```
readAndSkipBlanks = function(file, sep=",", ...) {
  # read the headers of the file
  headers = unlist(strsplit(x = readLines(file, n=1), split = sep))
  isBlank = headers == "" # detect the blank columns
  ind = rle(isBlank)$lengths # how many data and blank columns
  isData = rle(isBlank)$values # TRUE for blanks
  n = length(ind) 
  # start and end of data columns
  inds = cbind(cumsum(c(1, ind[-n])), cumsum(ind)) 
  inds = inds[!isData, ] # data only
  # read the data
  data = read.csv(file=file, sep=sep, ...)
  output = list()
  # loop over the datasets
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(inds))) {
    # this creates a list, each element a dataset
    output[[i]] = data[, inds[i, 1]:inds[i,2]]
  }
  return(output)
}
```

and

```
readAndSkipBlanks("test.csv")

[[1]]
  testA1 testA2 testA3
1      1      1      1
2      2      2      2
3      3      3      3
4      4      4      4
5      5      5      5

[[2]]
  testB1 testB2
1      1      1
2      2      2
3      3      3
4      4      4
5      5      5

[[3]]
  testC1 testC2 testC3 testC4
1      1      1      1      1
2      2      2      2      2
3      3      3      3      3
4      4      4      4      4
5      5      5      5      5

[[4]]
  testD1 testD2
1      1      1
2      2      2
3      3      3
4      4      4
5      5      5
```

Comment: Thank you. It will take some time to understand all this. I have never written functions in R, and will have to look up a lot of R expressions.